# How to fix 'unrecognized rule' and 'Fatal parse 'errors on Flex code generator?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I'm on my way to create small compiler for a general algorithmic code in French by using Flex/Lex , I don't know the real concept of it and some base notation...

Here is the Flex code:

```
%{
#include "MiniCompil.tab.h"
#include<stdio.h>
%}
espace [" "]
chiffre [0-9]
lettre [a-z A-Z]
Id      {lettre}({lettre}|{chiffre})*
Int {chiffre}
Rl {Int}/.{chiffre}
Nb      {chiffre}*
Char  {lettre}
CDC {lettre}+
%%
{Nb}     {yylval.entier=atof(yytext);return(NB);}
{Id}     {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(ID);}
{ Rl }   {yylval.reel=atof(yytext);return(RL);}
{ Int } { yylval.entier=atof(yytext); return(INT);}
{ Char } {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(CHAR);}
{Cdc } {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(CDC);}
{Bool } {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(BOOL);}
Algorithme       {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(ALGORITHME);}
Debut            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(DEBUT);}
Fin              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FINN);}
Debut            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(DEBUTF);}
FinF             {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FINF);}
Variables        {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(VARIABLES);}
Fonction         {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FONCTION);}
Procedure        {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(PROCEDURE);}
Var              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(VAR);}
Si               {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(SI);}
Sinon                {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(SINON);}
Alors            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(ALORS);}
Finsi            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FINSII);}
Pour                 {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(POUR);}
A                {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(A);}
Pas              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(PAS);}
Faire            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FAIRE);}
FinPour          {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FINPOUR);}
Tantque          {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(TANTQUE);}
FinTq            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(FINTQ);}
Repeter          {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(REPETER);}
Jusqua           {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(JUSQUA);}
Selon              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(SELON);}
Autres          {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext); return(AUTRES);}
Sin                {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(SIN);}
Cos              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(COS);}
Tan              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(TAN);}
Log              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(LOG);}
Mod              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(MOD);}
Div              {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(DIV);}
Lire            {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext); return(LIRE);}
Ecrire           {yylval.chaine=strdup(yytext);return(ECRIRE);}
"("                return(OV);
")"                return(FER);
";"                return(PVER);
","                return(VER);
"+"                return(PLUS);
"*"                return(FOIS);
"-"                return(MOINS);
"<"                return(INF);
">"                return(SUP);
"<="               return(INFEG);
">="               return(SUPEG);
"<-"               return(AFFEC);
"=="               return(EGAL);
"<>"               return(DIFF);
"And"              return(AND);
"Or"               return(OR);
":"                return(DP);
["]["]           return(DQ);
['][']               return(UQ);

{espace}+

"\n"              return(FIN);
"."  return(ERREUR);
%%
```

And when I run my code on the command line I get these errors:

```
MiniCompil.l:78: unrecognized rule
MiniCompil.l:78: fatal parse error
```

the line 78 represent the last line of the code which is written on it %%...

What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the five lines starting at line 17:

```
 { Rl }   {yylval.reel=atof(yytext);return(RL);}
```

You cannot put a space inside a `{...}` macro expansion. That confuses (f)lex. That rule and the next four need to be written without extra spaces:

```
{Rl}   {yylval.reel=atof(yytext);return(RL);}
```

Also, many of your macro definitions are wrong. You should reread the [flex manual page on the syntax of patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). For example,

```
espace [" "]
```

defines a macro which recognises either a space or a double quote. (The fact that the double quote appears twice in the pattern doesn't make any difference.)

Similarly, the pattern in

```
lettre [a-z A-Z]
```

will recognise either a letter or a space character.

Really, you don't need all those macros since (f)lex already provides you with simple self-documenting named character classes:

- `[[:digit:]]` — what you've defined as `{chiffre}`
- `[[:alpha:]]` — the correct version of `{lettre}`
- `[[:blank:]]` — space or tab character, probably what you meant by `{espace}`

And `{Id}` could be written as `[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]`.

The advantage of using standard regular expressions is that it makes it clear what your patterns mean to anyone reading your code, without having to look up what your macro definitions expand to (particularly when the macro definitions have errors in them).

Finally, when you put the `{Id}` pattern before all those keywords, you guarantee that none of the keywords can be recognised by the scanner, because the pattern which comes first in the file (`{Id}`) is preferred. See [the next chapter in the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html) for details. (This also applies to a number other patterns, such as `{Char}` and `{CDC}`. Frankly I don't understand at all what your intention with those patterns is.)

And there are a number of other errors, some of which flex will detect. For example, the macro `{Bool}` is not defined. And the definition of `{Rl}` is wrong on a number of levels. (Did you mean `\.`? Even so, the part of the pattern before and after that are wrong. And why do you feel the need to have two different macros which both mean "a single digit"?)